# VS Code, когда свожу курсор с линии - пропадает табуляция

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, форматирование

Я недавно перешел с `Visual Studio` на `Visual Studio Code`, и меня беспокоит одна неприятная мелочь. При неведении курсором на любую строку, я хочу чтобы он автоматически вставал в конец строки, но в `Visual Studio Code` такого не происходит. Так же и с табуляцией, активная строка всегда переносит курсор в свой конец, все остальные же этого не делают.

Возможно ли это исправить?

[image: Пример]

Заранее благодарен за овтет.

Comment: Для VS Code настройка называется `Editor: Trim Auto Whitespace` (Remove trailing auto inserted whitespace)

Comment: @insolor Спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insolor` дал правильный ответ:

Для VS Code настройка называется Editor: `Trim Auto Whitespace` (Remove trailing auto inserted whitespace). Надо убрать галочку с этого чекбокса.

[image: Пример]